# Error while generating smooth curve with vertical lines and date data: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'numpy.float64'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a smooth curve with vertical lines.
I used scipy.interpolate to smooth the curve, however for some reason the vertical lines don't appear in the graph anymore. and i get the following error:

```
"'<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'numpy.float64'"
```

Graph

[image]

Code

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = list(df['Date'])
print(dates)
dates_list = []

for date in dates:
    dates_list.append(datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))

from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
# plt.plot(dates_list, saudi_cases['Cases'], label="cases");
x =  np.linspace(0, 48, num=49)
A_tck = splrep(x, list(saudi_cases['Cases']))

dates = dates_list

x_new = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200)
A_new = splev(x_new, A_tck)
plt.plot(x_new, A_new, label='A')
plt.xticks(x, dates, size='small')
plt.suptitle('Saudi Arabia Cases')
plt.xlabel("Dates")
plt.ylabel("Cases")
plt.axvline(pd.Timestamp('2020-03-09'),color='r',label="event1")
plt.text(pd.Timestamp('2020-03-09'),99,'event1',rotation=90,fontsize=12)
plt.axvline(pd.Timestamp('2020-03-15'),color='b',linestyle='dashed')
plt.text(pd.Timestamp('2020-03-15'),99,'event2',rotation=90,fontsize=12)
plt.axvline(pd.Timestamp('2020-03-16'),color='b',linestyle='dashed')
plt.text(pd.Timestamp('2020-03-16'),99,'event3',rotation=90,fontsize=12)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe replace `pd.Timestamp('2020-03-09')` with `np.datetime64('2020-03-09')`?  Not sure that will help.  What is the full traceback?

Comment: The x-axis is numeric (linspace between min and max) when you plot the interpolated curve, whereas the x-axis for the vertical lines is pd.Timestamp.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. what I did is that I changed the x-axis to numerical values

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I solved it by converting the dates to numbers using matplotlib's [dates API](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html). I think I had to use `date2num`, but there are several other options available.

It doesn't look like your code sample is complete. (`df` is undefined.) It's easier for people to confirm that their answers work if you provide a complete sample.